# Exception during redirection in NestJS Guard - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: express, nestjs

I have seen many posts regarding this error but was not able to figure out how to fix this as I am unable to understand the mistake, hence I was required to create new question.

I have controller that serves my HTML page which is below:

```
@Get()
      @UseGuards(MyGuard)
      root(@Res() res): void {
        return res.sendFile(
          path.resolve(
            '../dist/index.html'
          )
        );
      }
```

This route is protected by a guard which in turn takes me to a redirection url which issues me a token and I will be required to set this token as a cookie in my response. Idea is to block unauthorized user from seeing the application via this guard and redirect the user to error page.

The Guard logic looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
    export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor() {}
      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        const cookie = this.getookie(req);
        if (cookie found in cookie and is valid) {
          return true;
        }
        else if (token available in redirect url) {
          res.cookie('token', req.query['token']);
          return true;
        } 
        else if (token not available in route path) {
          const myRedirectionUrl = createRedirectionUrl(req);
          **// Error in below snippet
          res.writeHead(302, {
            Location: myRedirectionUrl  // <-- does some validation and redirects to url with token query string
          });
          res.end()**
        }
        else {
           return false
        } 
      }
    }
```

Though I get the request token am able to set cookie and flow works as expected I always get exception on res.writeHead() which is called on the first request (which does not contain any cookie or query param).

> (node:26764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
>   at ServerResponse.header (C:\project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>   at ServerResponse.send C:\project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>   at ServerResponse.json (C:\project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>   at ExpressAdapter.reply (C:\project\node_modules@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express adapter.js:23:57)
>   at ExceptionsHandler.catch (C:\project\node_modules@nestjs\core\exceptions\base-exception-filter.js:41:24)
>   at ExceptionsHandler.next (C:\project\node_modules@nestjs\core\exceptions\exceptions-handler.js:15:20)
>   at C:\project\node_modules@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:12:35
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:26764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Any inputs should be of great help!!